# Delete texture in OpenGl 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vuforia

I'm working on an android application which augment 3D model when image target is detected using vuforia SDK. Nine 3D model are augmented at a same time. I have loaded texture using  GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0) method. So I've called below method for nine times and store the integer value of texture id in integer array.

```
public static int loadTexture(Bitmap bitmap)
{

    final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

    if (textureHandle[0] != 0)
    {          
        isaugmented1 = false;
        android.graphics.Matrix matrix = new android.graphics.Matrix();

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);

        // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

        // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
        bitmap = null;

    }

    if (textureHandle[0] == 0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
    }


    return textureHandle[0];
}
```

Now I want to delete that all nine texture, so I've called

```
GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1, temphandler, 0)
```

method in a loop as mentioned in below code. but as a result only last texture is deleted. I want to delete all texture which are stored.

```
 public void deleteTexture()
{
    if(mosaicHandler!=null){
        if(mosaicHandler.length>0)
        {
            Log.e("deleting", "texture");
            for(int i = 0; i<mosaicHandler.length;i++)
            {
                Log.e("deletingTexture", i+"");
                int [] temphandler = new int[1];
                temphandler[0] = mosaicHandler[i];                  
                GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1, temphandler, 0);
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to delete texture whose Id is stored in integer array?

Comment: How do you know that the textures were not deleted?

Answer (score 0):

To delete multiple textures at once, just follow the opengl api

https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteTextures.xml

Comment: thanks for your reply!! I've already tried this..but not working for me!!